# help me plz 2.1.2 Resolving Dependencies for osx pcl

Tags: ros, pcl, rosdep, homebrew, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in ros hydro osx homebrew

i'm working on 2.1.2 Resolving Dependencies
and take command to terminal

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y
```

but finally i can't pass it to 2.1.3 because my terminal show error

```
[
Error: No available formula for pcl_msgs  
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap ros/hydro  
Error: No available formula for flann   
executing command [brew install ros/hydro/pcl_msgs]   
Error: No available formula for pcl_msgs  
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap ros/hydro    
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install  
homebrew: command [brew install ros/hydro/pcl_msgs] failed ]
```

after i command

```
$ brew install ros/hydro/pcl_msgs
```

but terminal show this

```
Error: No available formula for pcl_msgs 
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap ros/hydro
```

after than I command

```
$ brew tap ros/hydro
```

terminal show this

```
Warning: Already tapped!
```

Could you help me solve this problem,please I'm really stuck
thank you sorry for bad English

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189196/help-me-plz-2.1.2-resolving-dependencies-for-osx-pcl/) by [ztitch](https://answers.ros.org/users/19956/ztitch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So these errors are really misleading. ROS packages are unfortunately not available as homebrew formulae yet, so `ros/hydro/pcl_msgs` does not exist. You will have to install it from source.

What instructions have you been following and what packages are your current workspace? You must have added something that depends of `pcl_msgs`. Please edit your question to contain this information.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0